# What do the number codes mean next to the WebSocket messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, debugging, websocket

I've just completed the simple chat client socket.io tutorial and I am inspecting the messages going between my browser and the Node.js server web socket using the Chrome WebSocket inspector.  There are numbers prefixed before the messages as depicted in my screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see there are messages with just '2' and '3' and next to my emits there are 42s going back and forth.  What do they mean?  Is there a list of the main message types I should familiarise myself with so I can learn about debugging Web Sockets?

Comment: not a part of sockets spec, must be something added by your client software, socket.io. good luck finding more info: socket.io seems to be about half ritual and superstition...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564877/what-do-these-numbers-mean-in-socket-io-payload/

Comment: @Evernoob: see my edit on the post above for extra details

Comment: Commented a moment ago by was really wrong. I found this tho: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol/issues/11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do these numbers mean in socket.io payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564877/what-do-these-numbers-mean-in-socket-io-payload)

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564877/what-do-these-numbers-mean-in-socket-io-payload).  As the comments say the number codes in your Websocket messages are **not part of Websocket**, they are added by the socket.io library.

The significance of numbers is found in [engine.io protocol](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol) and the [socket.io protocol](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol), and described in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24564877/1175496)

## engine.io protocol

So "just 2" and "just 3" you described are the "ping" and "pong"

> Here is the list of available packet types:
>
> | Type | ID | Usage |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | open | 0 | Used during the handshake. |
> | close | 1 | Used to indicate that a transport can be closed. |
> | ping | 2 | Used in the heartbeat mechanism. |
> | pong | 3 | Used in the heartbeat mechanism. |
> | message | 4 | Used to send a payload to the other side. |
> | upgrade | 5 | Used during the upgrade process. |
> | noop | 6 | Used during the upgrade process. |

## socket.io protocol

So the "42" you described is a combination of engine.io 4, which means "message", and socket.io 2, which means "event"

> Here is the list of available packet types:
>
> | Type | ID | Usage |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | CONNECT | 0 | Used during the connection to a namespace. |
> | DISCONNECT | 1 | Used when disconnecting from a namespace. |
> | EVENT | 2 | Used to send data to the other side. |
> | ACK | 3 | Used to acknowledge an event. |
> | CONNECT_ERROR | 4 | Used during the connection to a namespace. |
> | BINARY_EVENT | 5 | Used to send binary data to the other side. |
> | BINARY_ACK | 6 | Used to acknowledge an event (the response includes binary data). |