# How to write Websocket sampler request body in Jmeter

Tags: websocket, socket.io, jmeter

Example :

42/,["current_event",{"current_event":"onboarding","eligible":true,"isOnBoarded":true,"event":"5f4dba217f63c00bd40bd636","contestantor":"5f4dba147f63c00bd40bd635","lastContestantor":false}]

What are these starting numbers (42/,43/ etc)? and how to write proper request body in Websocket request-response sampler?

Answer (score 0):

You're [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564877/what-do-these-numbers-mean-in-socket-io-payload) who is [confused](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol/issues/11#issuecomment-94472277) by these magical numbers

> The `4` part comes from the `engine.io-protocol` (abstract transport layer) which means `message` and the `2` part comes from the `socket.io-protocol` (specific transport layer) which is the message type and means event, internally referenced as `MESSAGE_EVENT`.

So you can just record your scenario and leave these `42` and `43` and [variablize/correlate the payload](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) in the sampler's body.

More information:

- [socket.io-protocol](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol)
- [engine.io-protocol](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol)
- [5 Ways to Load Test Popular Chat Plugins with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-to-load-test-popular-chat-plugins-with-jmeter)